# Provide a combinatorial argument that proves $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-2}{k}+2\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k-2}$

Tags: combinatorics

> $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-2}{k}+2\binom{n-2}{k-1}+\binom{n-2}{k-2}$$

Someone please help me start this question, I am very lost and a bit confused ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the lefthand side, you count the number of ways to choose $k$ items from a collection of $n$ distinct items (say, the set $\{1, 2, \dots n\}$).

For the righthand side, focus in on the elements $1$ and $2$. When you make a choice of $k$ elements, you must include

- both $1$ and $2$,
- exactly one of $1$ or $2$, or
- neither $1$ nor $2$.

Do you see how the righthand side enumerates these situations?

Comment: I'm still lost,

Comment: For example, in how many ways could you select $k$ items from $n$ items if you are forced to include both items 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

Use this combinatorial identity: ${{n}\choose{k}}={{n-1}\choose{k-1}}+{{n-1}\choose{k}}$ from Pascal's triangle. We then see that:

$${{n}\choose{k}}={{n-1}\choose{k-1}}+{{n-1}\choose{k}}$$

Now use the same identity and apply it to ${{n-1}\choose{k-1}}$ and ${{n-1}\choose{k}}$.

$${{n}\choose{k}}=({{n-2}\choose{k-2}}+{{n-2}\choose{k-1}})+({{n-2}\choose{k-1}}+{{n-2}\choose{k}})$$

$${{n}\choose{k}}={{n-2}\choose{k-2}}+2{{n-2}\choose{k-1}}+{{n-2}\choose{k}}$$

Answer (score 0):

> \begin{align*}
>   (1+x)^{n} &= (1+x)^{2}(1+x)^{n-2} \\
>   &=(1+2x+x^2) (1+x)^{n-2} \\
> \end{align*}

Comparing coefficients of $x^{k}$ where $2\le k \le n-2$, the result follows.